# Ubuntu always restarts on shutdown

Tags: 22.04, shutdown

Whenever I shutdown Ubuntu, it always restarts

I have seen that a lot of people have asked the question above, but I think my situation might be different

I have Windows installed on a separate partition. Whenever I shutdown Windows it stays shutdown and doesn't restart. This leads me to believe that the problem isn't related to the *BIOS* (and none of the BIOS power settings allow for an automatic restart anyway)

Is there any purely Ubuntu OS setting that might be triggering a restart?

**EDIT**: Shutdown is performed via the system panel in the top right corner.

Restart also occurs when performing shutdown using `systemctl poweroff` or `shutdown now`commands in the terminal

**EDIT 2**: Having performed Waltinator's instructions, there are no obvious problems indicated in the logs. The computer completes a shutdown, and then boots, without any indication (that I can see) that something went wrong. No reason is given for the boot either.

```
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: Reached target System Shutdown.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: Reached target Late Shutdown Services.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Deactivated successfully.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: Finished System Power Off.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: Reached target System Power Off.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd[1]: Shutting down.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
Nov 23 08:09:07 computername systemd-journald[381]: Journal stopped
-- Boot f6afdb5b374443c0b75cf586919542ba --
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel: Linux version 6.2.0-37-generic (buildd@bos03-amd64-055) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #38~22.04.1->
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic root=UUID=fbf8902f-4eb5-4b1e-b079-899f72ab1846 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Nov 23 08:09:35 computername kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
```

Thanks

Comment: For Ubuntu, or Linux in general, as shutdown is supposed to be a shutdown and a restart is a restart. There is no setting which makes a shutdown a restart. 
Please edit your question and add how you shutdown Ubuntu.
Please also try to shutdown Ubuntu from the terminal: open a terminal and then enter `systemctl poweroff` and press enter.

Comment: First step is to put a pin in the timestream with
```
date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp
``` Then, do your suspend/shutdown thing. When your system is usable again,
```
sudo journalctl --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"
``` This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. Some messages relate to your problem.

Comment: @noisefloor question edited. same result when performing systemcrl poweroff

Comment: Can you try the `shutdown now` command too??

Comment: @waltinator question edited with result of your request

Comment: @Ajay same result

Comment: Can you check your BIOS again and check for **Wake On X**? Disable each one of them or set them to 0

Comment: There are two options "Power On When X" (AC Detected and Lid is Opened). Both are and always have been off

Comment: Please try disconnecting your LAN, USB, and AC adapter and shut down again. I'm sorry it's getting long but need to check all these to figure out the cause

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149862/discussion-between-ajay-and-silaf).

Comment: Behaviour remains the same when everything is plugged out. Even with WLAN turned off.

Comment: Sorry I don't really have time for a chat anytime soon, and I haven't been back here since I posted my last comment

Comment: the update to 23.04 happened automatically at some point in december and the problem is resolved now